# How to configure VXLAN over linux bridge?

Tags: virtualization, linux-networking

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 which support VXLAN configuration. Currently I can add a VXLAN interface such that:

```
vagrant@ubuntu:~$ sudo ip link add vxlan1 type vxlan id 1 group 239.1.1.2
vagrant@ubuntu:~$ sudo ip addr add 10.0.1.2/24 dev vxlan1
vagrant@ubuntu:~$ sudo ip link set vxlan1 up
```

However, I was told to configure vxlan over a Linux bridge such that:

```
vagrant@ubuntu:~$ sudo ip link add vxlan1 type vxlan id 1 group 239.1.1.2 dev br0
vagrant@ubuntu:~$ sudo ip link set vxlan1 up
```

Where as br0 has other tap interfaces attached to it.

Below is the bridge info:

```
vagrant@i4-controller:~/workspace/devstack$ brctl show br1
bridge name bridge id       STP enabled interfaces
br1     8000.000c2987898a   no      vnet0
                                    vxlan1
```

I am kinda confused how will the vxlan interface work, does that mean all the tap interfaces will be tunneled to vxlan1?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I feel you are mixing couple of things here. As a one-liner, adding the tap interface/vxlan-interface to a linux bridge is no different from adding a physical interface (just that the other end of the interface is different)

More detailed answer, based on my inference of your question:

The vxlan interface that you have created provides the vxlan tunnel endpoint through which you can communicate with the entities in the other end of the tunnel. We can use vxlan tunnel to interconnect two VMs/docker-containers/LXCs which are not running the same physical system.

When doing that, we can create a veth/tap interface which can be used by the VM and this interface can be connected to the vxlan interface using the linux bridge.

In case of containers, this is not even required, you can push the vxlan interface directly into the container using the PHYS interface mode.